# Assuming the process stops exactly after six stages, what is the probability that the first coin issued is gold coin?

Tags: probability

A closed vessel has $5$ gold coins and $11$ silver coins. At each stage, a coin is randomly removed and replaced with a silver coin (i.e. the total number of coins in the vessel has not changed). The process is done over and over again until all the coins in the vessel are silver coins. Assuming the process stops exactly after six stages, what is the probability that the first coin issued is Gold coin?

Let $A$ be an event where the first coin was a gold coin. Let $B$ be the event where the process stops after six stages. We want $P(A|B)$. We can note that $P(A)=\frac{5}{16}$. But how can I find $P(B)$ and $P(B|A)$?

Comment: What does "issued" mean? Does it mean "first coin removed"?

Comment: Notice that regardless of the draws, you fulfill exactly once the probabilities $5/16, 4/16, 3/16, 2/16 \text{and} 1/16$. So to find $P(B)$ simply multiply them with the probability of one bad draw. So you have to add the probabilities corresponding to drawing a silver in your first, second, ... draw. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Reading your question again. I think I completely misunderstood your question. So removing my current answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having understood your question now, @BrianMoehring solution works well. But if your question is specifically about finding $P(B)$ and $P(B|A)$, here is how you can find them.

Event $A$ is the first coin being gold. Event $B$ is removing $5$ gold coins in six stages.

$P(A) = \dfrac{5}{16}$

$P(B)$ is the probability of removing $5$ gold coins in exact $6$ stages. So the sixth coin has to be the gold coin. So here are the $5$ possibilities -

$\{S, G, G, G, G, G\}, \{G, S, G, G, G, G\}, \{G, G, S, G, G, G\}, \{G, G, G, S, G, G\}, \{G, G, G, G, S, G\}$.

$P(B) = \dfrac{5}{16}.\dfrac{4}{16}.\dfrac{3}{16}.\dfrac{2}{16}.\dfrac{1}{16} \, (\dfrac{11}{16}+\dfrac{12}{16}+\dfrac{13}{16}+\dfrac{14}{16}+\dfrac{15}{16})$

$P(B|A)$ is the probability of event $B$ (which is removing $5$ gold coins in six stages) given event $A$ (which is the first coin being gold).

$P(B|A) = \dfrac{4}{16}.\dfrac{3}{16}.\dfrac{2}{16}.\dfrac{1}{16} \, (\dfrac{12}{16}+\dfrac{13}{16}+\dfrac{14}{16}+\dfrac{15}{16})$

$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)} = \dfrac{54}{65}$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an intuitive solution (which admittedly doesn't answer your questions about $P(B), P(B\mid A)$ but I feel it's interesting in its own right)

First note that the process stopping after exactly six stages is equivalent to exactly one of the first five draws is silver and the sixth draw is gold.

Under this assumption, the probability that draw $n \in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is silver is proportional to the number of silver coins in the vessel at the $n$th draw, which is $10+n$.  In particular the conditional probability that the first draw is silver is $$\frac{10+1}{\sum_{n=1}^5(10+n)} = \frac{11}{65}$$ and so the conditional probability that the first draw is gold is $$1-\frac{11}{65} = \frac{54}{65}$$

Comment: Yes your solution works well. I somehow misunderstood the question earlier. Have edited my answer to get to $P(B)$ and $P(B|A)$.